# Need current iPhone's visual voicemails to transfer to new iPhone's visual voicemail, same carrier (AT&T)

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, setup, voicemail, visual-voicemail

I am updating my AT&T iPhone XR Pro Max to an AT&T iPhone 12 Pro Max.
I need to make sure my visual voicemails get transferred so they can be viewed and opened on the Voicemail app on the new iPhone. It is not good enough to export them as VoiceMemos or Notes.
I run iCloud backups, but I could run backups onto my MacBook it that's what it takes to move them properly. It is not clear whether either backup type backs up visual voicemails and restores them as voicemails via restoring the backup onto a new device.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The voicemails themselves are stored on ATT servers. Getting a new iPhone *shouldnt* impact your VM. Follow the directions on activating your new phone and you should be fine. As far as I know there isn’t a way to backup those VMs.

Comment: Thanks -- I will try this and hope for the best. I had read elsewhere that once the voicemails have downloaded into the Voicemail, they were erased of the ATT servers. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust the carrier to keep all voicemails once they know it’s downloaded to your device.

Get a tool to archive them if you can’t lose them is my advice.

- http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

Doing the setup of the devices wired to each other is your best bet if you have not tested a full backup of your phone to a computer. Apple says they back up ALL DATA when you backup to macOS, but I can’t say for sure if all voicemail are in that category. You could test backing up the old phone and then set up the new phone by restoring the backup from the computer before you terminate service on the old phone if you want to be sure you are covered.